# HTMX select item in list with arrows

Tags: htmx

I would like to recreate google search box with HTMX.

But I have some issues like how to highlight row in suggestions. Only way I know how to do it with HTMX is call service which will render new html. This seems dumb, and I would like to do it on client side. But I would also like to avoid writing js.

In addition, highlighted item should be shown in input box and if user starts typing it should continue. But if it tries to go back with arrow (e.g. presses left arrow key) it should not use highlighted item.

I did made this with js but I would like to make it without explicit js.
I have also tries with datalist but since options can be different then input, browser filters out those options. Also it does not really do what I would like (auto filling input box with highlighted item).

Comment: `This seems dumb, and I would like to do it on client side.`
then why even bother with htmx?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how HTMX works. It calls an endpoint which generates HTML in response. You simply display the HTML where you want to.

The idea is to not write any JS (or very little indeed).

Highlighting, autocomplete, etc. should be using HTMX only.

If you know JS, it will take time to "unlearn", which may seem counterintuitive at first.

You may want to check how animations work here:
https://htmx.org/examples/animations/